# Java library class not recognized?

Tags: java, api, lucene

I am importing this following  :

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemmer
```

in Java program. The whole package is available in refrenced library.

I tried importing

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemFilter
```

and

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
```

both are working **fine** except the first one mentioned
Can anybody point out why ?!

Comment: can you verify that the class you're looking for is inside the loaded jar file? Try looking at "jar -tvf mylibrary.jar" and see if it's in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemmer` is not a public package which is why you cannot import it. If you look at this package inside the library, you'll notice that it begins with `class PorterStemmer` instead of `public class PorterStemmer`.

Comment: It's not private. .it has default access. You can only have nested private classes

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a different version of the Lucene JAR that doesn't contain the class that's failing to work.  Open the JAR with WinZip, 7Zip, or some other tool and see if that class is indeed missing.  If it is, you either need to find a version of the JAR that has it or rewrite your code to use an alternative.

Comment: I have lucene-3.4.0 2/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar  and I can see the class PorterStemmer.class in this package

Comment: In error it does not say that the "class cannot be resolved" It says "import org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemmer is not visible "

Comment: I see the .class file in the JAR file, but it's not listed in the javadocs.  I think Thorbjorn has the answer: it's not public.